# How to know record is inserted or not in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The return type of method collection.insertOne(document) is void.Then how can i know wether the record is inserted or not in java application (not through mongo shell)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertOne-TDocument-), an exception will be thrown when the insert fails.

Throws:

- `MongoWriteException` - if the write failed due some other failure
  specific to the insert command
- `MongoWriteConcernException` - if the write failed due being unable to
  fulfil the write concern
- `MongoException` - if the write failed due some other failure